# Datetime collection needs to parse out date and only keep time

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-forms

I am collecting datetime data in a form to be saved in a model. Like this

```
start_time = forms.DateTimeField()
```

Now I want to take the data that I have collected and only extract the date. I want the date to then be formatted in the following way (year-month-day):

```
2013-04-19
```

What would be the easiest way to do this? Can someone provide examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
start_time.srtftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Why do I have a feeling that you are asking smth more than it?

Comment: I'd probably use `start_time.date().iso_format()` but this works too.

Comment: Thanks Alecxe, that is all I was asking. Peter DeGlopper, does isoformat() need to be specified a format to follow? And why do you prefer it to strftime()?

Comment: `isoformat` returns a date in the predefined string format YYYY-MM-DD. I mildly prefer it just for readability/aesthetic reasons, but there's nothing at all wrong with `srtftime`.